# Java inheritance: is the parent class instantiantiated every time a child class extends it?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, inheritance

I want to provide a basic functionality for all the fragments in my project.

The parent fragment (**FragmentP**) itself extends the android `Fragment` class. Here I'll provide a common functionality for all the fragments that will extend it.

Now my questions are:

1. How does the fragment lifecycle of **FragmentP** differ from all its children?
2. When is **FragmentP** created and destroyed? Is it re-created (re-instantiated) when any of it's children is created (instantiated)?

Comment: I advise you to read some documentation on the basics of POO before starting Android development. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you extend a class, the only thing you do is **specialize** the parent's functionalities.

Now, if you call `super();` in your child constructor, it doesnt instantiate a parent object. Instead it runs the parent constructor before it runs the code in your child class constructor.
This is commonly used when your child classes need to have the same behaviour to be executed at instantiation time.

Edit:

Let's say you have a super class `Vehicle` and two children `Car` and `Quad`.
Both of these vehciles have 4 wheels. Thus, your super constructor could initialize a `wheel` field to the value of **4**.

But both children have differences :
For example, a `Car` has windows, when a `Quad` don't have.
So your `Car` constructor should initialize a window field, and your `Quad` constructor shouldnt.

Answer (score 1):

No, it has nothing to do with instantiating. The concept of inheritance is that you **extend** the functionality of a pre-existing class and in this case it's a `FragmentP` with extended methods, fields and so on.

It's still a `Fragment` with the usual lifecycle from android.

Answer (score 1):

1) When instantiating a class, no parent class gets instantiated, though you must call the constructor of your parent class:

```
public childClass(){
   super();
}
```

But only one instance lives, which is childClass, no instance of parentClass will be present in memory. So the lifecycle is the same for any class, inheritance is a static procedure, not a dynamic one. This means that it happens during compile time, and not during execution.

2) FragmentP is only instantiated when you explicitly decide to do so, depending on the instantiation strategy you chose (Factory, constructor, builder, etc). And it's destroyed (actually collected by the garbage collector) when there are no remaining live references to the instance.